# Parsing xml string containing multiple xml documents

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a **string** like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><abc><xyz/></abc><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><abc><xyz/></abc>
```

Is there a way in Xquery to obtain two document nodes from it? Each document will have `abc` as its root element.

Comment: You might be able to split the individual documents using string function, and then parse the individual documents as XML. I'm not sure whether you can do this in Marklogic though (and if so, how).

Comment: The most obvious solutions are going to be prone to bugs (say, if you have a string that looks like `<?xml` inside a CDATA section).

Comment: The example shown is not valid XML, and not parsable by any XML 1.0+ compliant parser.  Whether thats good or bad -- its the same result.

Comment: The example shown is not valid XML, and not parsable by any XML 1.0+ compliant parser.   If you can get the input format changed, a much more common format is to wrap all the documents as children of a root element, then its easy. If you cant change the input data at all, then unless you can be assured of a certain pattern at the start or between document fragments this isnt a solvable problem in general.   You might guess at things until it works and maybe it will work all the time for the data your given.   Or maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

How about tokenizing on `<?xml`, and then applying `xdmp:unquote` on each item in the sequence?

HTH!

Comment: Yes I had initially thought of that but then realised <?xml could be inside a CDATA . Problem is Java is sending me this string.

Comment: If it's output by Java code what are the odds it will use CDATA? Most programmatic serializers won't ever.  So maybe you got lucky and the ugly hack is sufficient.